# Granting an uber flexible user acess/modify rights system

Tags: c#, admin, command-pattern, access-rights

I am developing an application where the client needs and *extremely* flexible user rights system. For example, a user should be able to have update rights in Form A but not in Form B (which prevents me from defining broad update rights). Admin should also be able to transfer specific rights to a user.

I was thinking of using the `Command Pattern` with `CanExecute` method but not really sure how I can use it in such a dynamic/specific way. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar situation in my application, which can be extended via plugins and the plugins can bring in their own permission. I solved that the following way:

- static/common `PermissionManager`
- very module/form/plugin can register its available permissions in the manager
- the "permission manager UI" lists all available permissions and lets the admin assign them to users
- on access every module/form/plugin asks the manager if the current user has the permission

Simplified class structure:

```
public class PermissionManager
{
    public static Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> AvailablePermissions { get; set; }
    public static bool? Can(User user, string permission)
    {
        // check DB
        return DENIED ? false : (ALLOWED ? true : null);
    }
}

public class MyPlugin : IPlugin
{
    public void Init()
    {
        PermissionManager.AvailablePermissions["MyPlugin"] = 
            new List<string>() { "Permission1", "Permission2" };
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        if (PermissionManager.Can(user, "Permission1") != true)
            throw new NotAllowedException();
        // do work
    }
}
```

This is the basic patter I use. Of course you should use constants or similar for the permission names/keys. The admin UI can then iterate `AvailablePermissions` in the configuration UI.

In the DB I have something like the following (EF Code-First):

```
public class UserProfilePermissions
{
    public UserProfile User { get; set; }
    public Permission Permission { get; set; }
    public bool IsAllowed { get; set; }
}
public class Permission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
}
```

So for every permission there is one `Permission` entry created (on the first assignment) in the DB and mapped via the mapping table using the `IsAllowed` to define "ALLOWED" or "DENIED".
The `null` value defines a not set permission so default values can be used (=> not set permission does not always say "DENIED").
The mapping table can also be used in the same style for e.g. roles.

Comment: Thanks for your answer this looks very nice. How is your design on DB side ? For example do you manually specify the type of rights for that module in a table ?

Comment: @Cemre: Added the basic schema.